# Why does latex reference my section and not my table

Tags: tables

I have the following table:

```
\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l|  |X}
    
    \multicolumn{1}{c||}{\textit{\textbf{Causes}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{\textbf{Definitions}}} \tabularnewline \hline
    x & A x \\ \hline
    x & x \\ \hline
    x & x \\ \hline
    x & x \\  \hline
    x & x\\ \hline
    x & x \\ \hline
    x & x \\ \hline
    x & x \\ 
    
    \end{tabularx}
\textbf{\caption{OAB - causes and definitions \cite{pristyn_care_team_4_2021,1997,1997_myo,2005,2001_MJ}}}
\label{table 1}   
\end{table}
```

when I use \ref{table 1} it will reference the section the table is in and not the table itself. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I have a caption right before my \label

Comment: oh it's inside a group so tex will have forgotton about that by the time it sees `\label` (don't place `\caption` in `\textbf` the caption formatting is part of the document setup

Comment: Thank you, I switched the commands around and now it works. Brill!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You should put `\textbf{}` inside `\caption{}` so You will have

```
\caption{\textbf{OAB - causes and definitions \cite{pristyn_care_team_4_2021,1997,1997_myo,2005,2001_MJ}}}
```

Comment: Thank you - this fixed my issue !

Comment: or better you should delete `\textbf` there should not be formatting in the caption. (unless you also want it bold in the list of tables, for exampel)

Comment: You are welcome @Kieran Holmes-Martin